# data-role not working when creating dynamically please help me out

Tags: jquery-mobile

i have one image  and one div.i am dragging and dropping that image to my div.on drop of that image i am creating a j query mobile header dynamically.but it is not working.

`drag code ........`
 `$("#frame").droppable({`

`drop: function (event, ui) {` 
`var header1 = '<div id="headrr" data-role="header" ><h3 >Header</h3></div>';`
                               `$("#frame").append(header1);`

and my page is jquery mobile page.i have added all the scripts ..
my main problem is jquery mobile UI is not working when created dynamically using java script or jquery.
and it is working fine without dynamical generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin (listview button, select, etc.).

```
$("#frame").trigger('create');
```